# Running visual studio solution on local host Google Chrome

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, iis

When trying to run a visual studio application on localhost using Google Chrome, I always get this screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPCuL.jpg

It seems to be automatically redirecting to the default page of IIS.

When running on Internet explorer it runs ok. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Hey wait a moment are you looking for localhost or not? I mean, are you accessing from the same computer or not?

## TO ACCESS FURTHER INFO

to discover which process is using the defaul port for http 80 run nestat -ano and look for pid that has port 80 in his local address and the kill it with taskkill

## TO DISABLE IIS

To disable IIS you have to go in settings -> "turn windows features on or off" and deselect "Internet information service"

for more info: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-windows-features-on-off#1TC=windows-7

Comment: I want to run the website I am working on in visual studio on local host. This used to work fine before last week. All of a sudden it began not running on Chrome but running ok on Internet explorer. I suspect the problem is from within chrome itself.